# Getting same values in uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nsarray

I am having an array which contains football match. i want to list the date and match name in title header in table view. i have take the date and match name and place it on the header section and its work correctly,**but i have a problem same value are appearing in all the section** where i did the mistake, can any one help me.

```
for (int i=[dataArr count]-1; i>=0; i--) {

  for (id item in tempArr)
  {
    if([@"Mexico: Copa Mexico - Clausura" isEqualToString:[item valueForKey:@"league_name"]]
       ||[@"Mexico: Liga De Ascenso - Clausura" isEqualToString:[item valueForKey:@"league_name"]]
       ||[@"Mexico: Primera Division - Clausura" isEqualToString:[item valueForKey:@"league_name"]])

      if([[dataArr objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToString:[item valueForKey:@"match_formatted_date"]])
      {

        NSMutableDictionary *tempDic =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [tempDic setValue: [item valueForKey:@"match_formatted_date"]  forKey:@"match_formatted_date"];
        [tempDic setValue: [item valueForKey:@"league_name"]  forKey:@"league_name"];


        if (![titleheader containsObject:tempDic])
        {

          [titleheader addObject:tempDic];
        }

      }
  }

}
NSLog(@"titleheader:%@",titleheader);


for (int i= 0; i<[titleheader count]; i++) {

  tempArry =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

  for (id item in tempArr)
  {
    NSMutableDictionary *tempdic = [titleheader objectAtIndex:i];


    if([[tempdic valueForKey:@"match_formatted_date"] isEqualToString:[item valueForKey:@"match_formatted_date"]]&& [[tempdic   valueForKey:@"league_name"] isEqualToString:[item valueForKey:@"league_name"]])
    {

      [tempArry addObject:item];
    }
  }

  NSLog(@"nslog:%@",tempArry);

  NSMutableDictionary *tempDic =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
  [tempDic setValue:tempArry forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];

  [datas addObject:tempDic];


}
[table reloadData];
```

---

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  array = [[datas objectAtIndex:section]valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",section] ];
  NSLog(@"nslog1234:%@",array);
  return [array count];
}
```

this is the output i am getting [image: same value]
i am having different values in each section.but i am getting like above image. help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following `method`..

If all works fine then replace `text` with your `Array object value`.

To get particular `index object` you can use `variable Section`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as CustomHeaderCell
    headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()

    switch (section) {
    case 0:
      headerCell.headerLabel.text = "Europe";
      //return sectionHeaderView
    case 1:
      headerCell.headerLabel.text = "Asia";
      //return sectionHeaderView
    case 2:
      headerCell.headerLabel.text = "South America";
      //return sectionHeaderView
    default:
      headerCell.headerLabel.text = "Other";
    }

    return headerCell
  }
```